# Highlighting certain characters in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm creating a simple text editor in Python 3.4 and Tkinter. At the moment I'm stuck on the `find` feature.

I can find characters successfully but I'm not sure how to highlight them. I've tried the tag method without success, error:

```
str object has no attribute 'tag_add'.
```

Here's my code for the find function:

```
def find(): # is called when the user clicks a menu item
    findin = tksd.askstring('Find', 'String to find:')
    contentsfind = editArea.get(1.0, 'end-1c') # editArea is a scrolledtext area
    findcount = 0
    for x in contentsfind:
        if x == findin:
            findcount += 1
            print('find - found ' + str(findcount) + ' of ' + findin)
    if findcount == 0:
        nonefound = ('No matches for ' + findin)
        tkmb.showinfo('No matches found', nonefound)
        print('find - found 0 of ' + findin)
```

The user inputs text into a scrolledtext field, and I want to highlight the matching strings on that scrolledtext area.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tag_add` to add a tag to a region. Also, instead of getting all the text and searching the text, you can use the `search` method of the widget. I will return the start of the match, and can also return how many characters matched. You can then use that information to add the tag.

It would look something like this:

```
...
editArea.tag_configure("find", background="yellow")
...

def find():
    findin = tksd.askstring('Find', 'String to find:')

    countVar = tk.IntVar()
    index = "1.0"
    matches = 0

    while True:
        index = editArea.search(findin, index, "end", count=countVar)
        if index == "": break

        matches += 1
        start = index
        end = editArea.index("%s + %s c" % (index, countVar.get()))
        editArea.tag_add("find", start, end)
        index = end
```

Comment: how would I go about removing the highlighting in a function?